# How to close multiple viewports

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

Pretty straight forward my question.

Comment: Nop..... It doesnt

Comment: Then please be a little more descriptive in what you're trying to accomplish, what doesn't work and why the linked answer doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I want to be using only one viewport. As you can see. I hope you can... I have 2 viewports in this very image. Area options doesnt help.

Comment: The *3D Viewport* isn't anything special in this regard. You can still place your mouse cursor between the areas, right-click and join them, just like the linked answer describes.

Comment: No you can't. I found out what to do. I have to make sure theres only one window in the middle, then i can join with the others.

Comment: Yes, you would (vertically) join the Outliner with Properties. The resulting area can then be (horizontally) joined with one of the 3D Viewports. Again there is nothing special about the 3D Viewport. You just can't directly join multiple areas at once (e.g. the 3D Viewport with the Outliner *and* the Properties). It's always one area with another area.

Comment: Althought the linked anwer did not say that, but ok thanks for helping.